# How to manage sub transactions in microservics env

Tags: java, microservices, message

We have microservice env with multiple service. the first service in the flow create correlationId (cid). and pass it from one service to another for future tracing purposes.

We do understand that each service need to create an additional "EventId" so it can be used internally. but that causing multiple issues.

1. it damage our deduplication mechanism
   we have deduplication mechanism which checks if the same cid arrives in the last 5 mins it will call it dedup and throw it away but
   if service A need to call service B multiple times under the same flow our dedup will throw away valid messages as they arnt real dedups
2. Shall we always create an internal eventId or only when we insert records to datasources  (e.g mysql)
3. will be great to have an example for such architecture

Comment: Your deduplication mechanism should check if that eventId was already successfully processed or not before throwing it away. You can also try adding a "CallId" in the eventId to different between different calls in the same flow.

Comment: Seems to me that this question will fit better on the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site

Comment: @Dherik when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)